# CSS two column turn to one on small screen

Tags: css, css-float, multiple-columns

I just starting turning away of doing all things in  and am playing with div and floats.

I have a homepage that need to have a two column in top and one beneath. 
[image: Big screen]

When the user have a small screen as a mobile, it need to put every box on each row as the example.
[image]

**What is the correct way of doing this?
This show the code: http://jsfiddle.net/boje/cMF4P/1/**

This is what the homepage do now.
[image]

Some of the code

```
/* =====  form2  ===== */
fieldset.fieldsetLeft {
    width:47%;
    float:left;
    padding: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}
fieldset.fieldsetRight {
    width: 45%;
    float:right;
    padding: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}
.clearBoth {
    clear: both;
}
```

Comment: do it with media queries

Comment: try float:left; on fieldset.fieldsetRight{
At least worked on jsfiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For smart phones & tablets you can make a dedicated css file which will overload the normal css style sheet:

In your header .html:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="only screen and (max-device-width: 1024px)" href="smart_tablet.css" type="text/css" />
```

Then into smart_tablet.css redefine the specific:

```
fieldset.fieldsetLeft {
    width:100%;
    float: none;
}
fieldset.fieldsetRight {
    width: 100%;
    float: none;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, for the solution. I need to change width to "auto" instead, else was the div to width for the screen.

Answer (score 1):

In your code you can change float right to float left on the right box and it will work as intended.

http://jsfiddle.net/PzAsJ/

```
fieldset.fieldsetRight {
    width: 45%;
    float:left;
    padding: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}
```

However have a look at *css3 media queries*, it gives you much more possibillities.

Comment: This do not turn over nice, beacuse of the width 45% make the iv only to use half of the screen. That's why I choose @ThierryT solution